# Behavior of materials on application of tension

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, mechanical-failure, deformation

Does a test body subjected to a strain that causes plastic deformation still have elastic recovery?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

In a perfectly elastoplastic material (where the stress-strain relationship is perfectly linear until the yield point and is then constant and equal to the yield point), the material will elastically recover all of its elastic deformation, but the plastic deformation will remain. This is the blue line in the figure below.

In (not perfectly) elastoplastic materials, the same general rule still applies, with recovery following the elastic deformation slope. This is the brownish line in the figure below.

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://materials.ucsb.edu/~matclass/101/pdffiles/Lecture_9.pdf)</sup>

The material has become "strain-hardened", which means it has a new yield point (at the point of release) but retains the same modulus of elasticity.

In non-elastoplastic materials (perfectly plastic, visco-elastic, visco-plastic, etc), things get messier, but I don't think the OP wants to go into that sort of detail.

Comment: @user32720: If so, please click on the "checkmark" to the left of my answer to mark it at the accepted answer.